# Delay LED activation in low battery indicator circuit

Tags: led, batteries

I’m currently using the circuit pictured bellow as a low battery indicator for a LiPo battery, which powers a vintage film camera. The camera draws power only in very short intervals (about 2-2.5s) each times it fires, the rest of the time it consumes basically nothing. The circuit lights up the LED when the battery hits around 3.75v (which is what I intend), indicating that the battery is low and it should be recharged.

[image: Text]

My problem is that when I use the camera it draws enough power from the battery to lower the voltage under the LED threshold for a very short time, so it blinks once quickly, each time I shoot it.

I would like to modify the circuit so the LED only turns on when the voltage remains at, or below, 3.75v for longer than 5 seconds.

How can I achieve this with as few components as possible?

I was thinking about maybe using a capacitor, so it would need to be “filled up” before the LED can be lit, not allowing it to turn on with just a quick pulse. Is this correct? How could I implement it?

I hope I’m clear enough with my question, I’m just starting with electronic circuits.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome! 2.5 seconds is a substantially long low pass filter. An MCU with 20 lines of code?

Comment: Yeah. A capacitor and a resistor would help isolate the circuit from the battery. Not sure why you need 5 seconds, though. Why? Does the camera really draw a lot of current for 2 or more seconds? (Charging itself up for a flash?)

Comment: If you increase the top 4K7 pull-up to something larger like 22K and add a 1000uF capacitor from the leftmost transistor's base to ground, you should get around 5 seconds before the base can reach ~0.6V to start conducting and turn on the LED. The led will slowly fade on tough.